# How to do data-binding with child-objects?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have three classes, which looks like this:

Parent class:

```
public class Artist
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public List<Album> Albums { get; set; }
    public string Biography { get; set; }
}
```

Middle Class:

```
public class Album
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int year { get; set; }
    public List<Artist> artists { get; set; }
    public List<Track> Tracks { get; set; }
}
```

And the child class:

```
public class Track
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int year { get; set; }
    public Int64 duration { get; set; }
    public List<string> genre { get; set; }
    public string searchpath { get; set; }
    public Album album { get; set; }

}
```

As you can see the Artist object has a list of albums, and the Album object has a list of tracks.

How would I go about binding this with a Listview if I have a List of Track (which has references to it's parents) if I for instance wanted a few Textblocks with the Artists name, Albums name and the track-title?

Is there any way to do `{Binding Path=track.album.name}` in the binding?

Comment: `Is there any way to do {Binding Path=track.album.name} in the binding?` **YES**. Have you tried it before posting this question?

Comment: I did, yes. Got some exception when I tried it, figured it was because of that. Have to look at my code a bit more.. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  If your DataContext is set to a Track object, you can use the path "album.name" to bind the track's album.